# popToViewController failed to pop to view error

Tags: swift, poptoviewcontroller

I am using the following code:

```
 @IBAction func popToRoot(sender:UIBarButtonItem){

    navigationController.popToViewController(foodforteethViewController(), animated: false)

}
```

This function is linked with a custom back button and the h file is linked in the objective-c/swift bridging file. The issue with this is that I get an error as below:

> 2014-07-19 23:35:40.842 FoodForTeeth[9040:238499] *** Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3232.3/UINavigationController.m:5345
>   2014-07-19 23:35:40.845 FoodForTeeth[9040:238499] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to get popped view controller.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023ec995 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010209b9a3 objc_exception_throw + 45
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023ec7fa +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>       3   Foundation                          0x0000000101cc637f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
>       4   UIKit                               0x0000000100b456b6 -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:] + 762
>       5   FoodForTeeth                        0x00000001000272fe _TFC12FoodForTeeth9dietDiary9popToRootfS0_FCSo15UIBarButtonItemT_ + 302
>       6   FoodForTeeth                        0x00000001000274f2 _TToFC12FoodForTeeth9dietDiary9popToRootfS0_FCSo15UIBarButtonItemT_ + 66
>       7   UIKit                               0x00000001009f76b6 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
>       8   UIKit                               0x00000001009f76b6 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
>       9   UIKit                               0x0000000100af91c0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000100af858f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000100a3c3b8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
>       12  UIKit                               0x0000000100a3cce3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
>       13  UIKit                               0x0000000100a0a1a1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
>       14  UIKit                               0x0000000100a1707a _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17591
>       15  UIKit                               0x00000001009f3269 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1967
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102322a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010231826d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023178a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023172d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
>       20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000105475bbc GSEventRunModal + 161
>       21  UIKit                               0x00000001009f6288 UIApplicationMain + 1282
>       22  FoodForTeeth                        0x0000000100054db3 main + 115
>       23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102b45145 start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

What's going wrong?

Comment: `reason: 'Failed to get popped view controller.'` is telling you the result of `foodforteethViewController()` is not an instance of the an object in the navigation stack. Please, add the declaration for `foodforteethViewController()` to your question.

Comment: Ah yes that's the case, I'm trying to go to that view controller even if the user hasn't navigated through it

Answer (score 1):

you can not pop a view controller which is not in `NavigationController` stack.You should pop like this

if you want pop to rootViewController than there is direct method use this

```
 @IBAction func popToRoot(sender:UIBarButtonItem){


        self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you will pop to the top of the current stack where there is a NavigationController. So placing UINavigationControllers in the right spots helps to achieve the desired results. As a side note, I was not able to use popToViewController as advertised (to pop to a higher level in the stack). I kept getting a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go back to a specific view controller would be to use unwind segues:
[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)